# Change symbology of interpolation layer using ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, symbology, inverse-distance-weighted

The code below creates many IDW rasters:

```
for date in all_dates:
    # Create a feature layer of each unique date
    where = "{0}=date '{1}'".format(arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(datasource=fc, field=date_field),
                                    date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
    arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(in_features=fc, out_layer='lyr', where_clause=where)

    # For each field interpolate. This is untested since I dont have spatial analyst
    for fieldname in value_fields:
        outIDW = Idw(in_point_features='lyr', z_field=fieldname,
                     cell_size=10)  # , {power}, {search_radius}, {in_barrier_polyline_features})
        outIDW.save(os.path.join(output_folder, '{0}_{1}.tif'.format(fieldname, date.strftime('%Y%m%d'))))
```

as you know the generated rasters are in black and white(color ramp)
I want to know if I can change them to other colors by using ArcPy not one by one in ArcMap.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "[Apply Symbology From Layer](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/apply-symbology-from-layer.htm)" tool does this. After the "`outIDW.save`" step, the layer will be the top-most layer in the map, so simply apply the symbology to the first layer in your map document. For example:

```
topLyr = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "*", df)[0]
symbologyLyr = r"C:\MyLayerFileFolder\someLayerFile.lyr"`
arcpy.management.ApplySymbologyFromLayer(topLyr, symbologyLyr)
```

(See [Saving layers and layer packages](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/working-with-layers/saving-layers-and-layer-packages.htm)).

Comment: Edit: @user181566, the code snippet originally had this as a .lyrx file, which is for ArcPro. Updated to .lyr file (https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/mapping/layerfile.htm).